# Gremin valueMap() all values inside lists

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

Say I do `g.V().has("id", 1).valueMap().next()`

The result is all in lists:

```
{
  "id": [1],
  "name" ["node1"]
}
```

How can I unfold all the inner lists so that it shows:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name" "node1"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you already answered your question in a sense - you use `unfold()`

```
g.V().has("id",1).
  valueMap().
    by(unfold())
```

That syntax only works on 3.4.0 when `by()` modulator [was added to](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/upgrade/#_modulation_of_valuemap) `valueMap()`. In earlier versions you can still do it but it's not as pretty:

```
g.V().has("id",1).
  valueMap().
  unfold().
  group().
    by(keys).
    by(select(values).unfold())
```

As you can see, you basically have to deconstruct the `Map` and then reconstruct it with `group()`. If you have multiple vertices you need to isolate the `unfold()` and so:

```
g.V().
  map(valueMap().
      unfold().
      group().
        by(keys).
        by(select(values).unfold()))
```

Comment: What are `keys` and `values` supposed to be?

Comment: I found them in `Column`, but I can't figure out which class to get the inner `select`

Comment: it's an anonymous traversal - you static import the double underscore class: `__`- http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/gremlins-anatomy/#_anonymous_traversals

Comment: Thanks. Got it to work. Just one small question. How do I apply this for a list of `valueMaps`?

Comment: when you have collections of anything (i.e. like List<Map>) to apply Gremlin to each "thing" in the collection you just need to `unfold()` it first (though some steps do allow `local` in-place application like `order()`).

Comment: My apologies but I don't understand the dsl well enough to accomplish this. Can you please provide the way to do this? I'm still trying to learn gremlin.

Comment: i misunderstood your question i think when i commented, please see my updated answer - i think that's what you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I needed.